# How to move the square to the destination?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

How to move the square to the destination? Square moves one pixel only when click the mouse? Sorry for my english.

```
window.onload = function(){
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var c = document.getElementById("game");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");   
init();
draw();

function init()
{
    document.addEventListener("click",paint,false);
}

function paint(e)
{
if(x<e.clientX) x++;
}

function draw()
{
    ctx.clearRect(x-1,y,1,15);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,15,15);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, adapted from [this article](http://www.somethinghitme.com/2013/11/13/snippets-i-always-forget-movement/) that I wrote a few months back.

The following is the piece to get it working

```
var tx = targetX - x,
    ty = targetY - y,
    dist = Math.sqrt(tx*tx+ty*ty);

velX = (tx/dist)*thrust;
velY = (ty/dist)*thrust;
```

We need to get the difference between the current position and targeted position (clicked area), we then get the distance, and make the velocity for x and y equal to the difference divided by the total distance multiplied by the speed of the object.

### Full working example and code

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/5d02ooaf/)**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = 500,
    height = 500,
    mX = width/2,
    mY = height/2;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

canvas.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    mX = e.pageX;
    mY = e.pageY;
});


var Ball = function (x, y, radius, color) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
    this.radius = radius || 10;
    this.speed = 5;
    this.color = color || "rgb(255,0,0)";

    this.velX = 0;
    this.velY = 0;
}

Ball.prototype.update = function (x, y) {
    // get the target x and y
    this.targetX = x;
    this.targetY = y;

    // We need to get the distance this time around
    var tx = this.targetX - this.x,
        ty = this.targetY - this.y,
        dist = Math.sqrt(tx * tx + ty * ty);

    /* 
     * we calculate a velocity for our object this time around
     * divide the target x and y by the distance and multiply it by our speed
     * this gives us a constant movement speed.
     */

    this.velX = (tx / dist) * this.speed;
    this.velY = (ty / dist) * this.speed;

    // Stop once we hit our target. This stops the jittery bouncing of the object. 
    if (dist > this.radius / 2) {
        // add our velocities
        this.x += this.velX;
        this.y += this.velY;
    }
};

Ball.prototype.render = function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    // draw our circle with x and y being the center
    ctx.arc(this.x - this.radius / 2, this.y - this.radius / 2, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
};

var ball1 = new Ball(width / 2, height / 2, 10);

function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ball1.update(mX, mY);
    ball1.render();

    requestAnimationFrame(render);

}

render();
```